# How does the 'Split()' function work in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm working in Visual Basic .NET, and I'm trying to get split to work.

Here is my code:

```
Public Sub CheckUpdate(ByVal FileURL As String)
        Dim instance As WebClient = New WebClient
        Dim ApplyTo As String = instance.DownloadString(FileURL)

        asd = ApplyTo.Split(",")
    End Sub
```

I use it like this:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        NewUpdate.CheckUpdate("version.txt")
        Label1.Text = NewUpdate.asd(0)
    End Sub
```

(Yeah, I know I use it on a local .txt file for now!)

So with asd(0) it reads the whole file. If I check asd(1) I get *IndexOutOfRange*. So how does Split() work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) returns an array with all the parts of the string separated by the specified character (in your case it's a comma). If asd(1) is out of range, that means you don't have any comma in your string.

Consider the following code:

```
Dim ApplyTo As String = "Test1,Test2"
asd = ApplyTo.Split(",")
Console.WriteLine(asd(0)) 'Prints "Test1"
Console.WriteLine(asd(1)) 'Prints "Test2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use Split:

```
  ' The below code will print D34Fge3 in a MsgBox
  Dim longstring as String = "D1111ZZ002CZ003*D34Fge3*ASDe3"
  Dim a() As String
  a = longstring.Split("*")
  MsgBox(a(1))
```

This code takes the longstring, and splits it based on the occurrence of *. You can then do whatever you want to each set by using a(0), a(1), and a(2).

Since there will only be three separate strings in this example calling a(3) or higher will result in an arrayoutofbounds exceptions. If I had set my split value to be a comma then I would be seeing an outofbounds exceptions when trying to call a(1).

Answer (score 0):

The Split Function returns an array "Split" on the character that you choose. In your case a comma. Your error is that you don't have anything in the string.

Answer (score 0):

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance
>   that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode
>   character array.

You are telling it to split on a comma, but there isn't any comma in the string you are splitting, so it just gives you the original result back. If you split on "." instead then asd(0) would be "version" and asd(1) would be "txt".

If that doesn't help the documentation can be found here: *[String.Split Method (System)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)*

Answer (score 0):

The following is the shorter way. We must use a loop:

```
For Each word As String In Split(txtSplit.Text, " ")
    txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text + word + vbCrLf
```